# Find String in Word an Select String including next word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I struggle with the following problem.
In an excel-VBA I want to find a certain string and and select the string as well as the next word in order to pass it to a variable.

Example:
The Search String is the word "Version" followed by a number. I now want to select both.

My code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim Dokument As String, Versionsnummer As String
Dim oAppWD As Object, oDoc As Object

Set oAppWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    If Not oAppWD Is Nothing Then
        oAppWD.Visible = True

        If oAppWD.Options.AllowReadingMode = True Then 'Word nicht im Lesemodus starten bei  _ Schreibgeschützten Dokumenten
            oAppWD.Options.AllowReadingMode = False
        End If

        Dokument = "I:Dokument\test.docx"

        Set oDoc = oAppWD.Documents.Open(Dokument)
        With oDoc
            With .Range
                With .Find
                    .Forward = True
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Text = "Version"
                    .MatchWholeWord = True
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                    .Execute
                End With
                If .Find.Found = True Then
                    .MoveEnd wdWord, 1
                    Versionsnummer = .Text
                End If
            End With
        End With
   End If
End Sub
```

However the "Versionsnummer" selects something in my inital excel file and not in the word document.
I would be happy for help.

Best regards

Peter

Comment: What is this line for? `If Not oAppWD Is Nothing Then
       End If`

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace:

```
           If .Find.Found = True Then     
               oDoc.Range.Row.Select
               'Selection.SelectRow
               Versionsnummer = oDoc.Range.Selection                 
           End If
```

with:

```
           If .Find.Found = True Then
               .MoveEnd wdWord, 1
               Versionsnummer = .Text
           End If
```

There is no need to *select* anything.